# A single word for the expression "One Thing In Common"?

Tags: grammar, writing

Is there a single word to replace "one thing in common"? I feel it might appear more professional, to be used say in academic work.

examples:

> - They've got one thing in common.
> - They have one common shared foundation.
> - They have one thing in common—*the user experience*.

Comment: I think you should mention what the "thing" is. There are many words that satisfy your question in its current form. Is the common 'thing' an interest? Is it a trait? is it a skill ? 
If you provide the context it would be better for the community to answer.

Comment: You mean  'genus'!

Comment: @mahmudkoya I thought the word 'genus' is only used in Biological works. Is it used it general usage?

Comment: It's a common biological term. I think you are looking for a word like it in general sense, right?

Comment: The OP's examples suggest that he is looking for a general term, yes.

Comment: Perhaps, "category": a group of people or things that are similar in some way?

Comment: *They share a common user interface*.

Comment: @Lawrence, not really. I guess, there is nothing out there that suggest differently. And I need to edit my question again. Wait.

Comment: You can say that they share one *similarity*.

Comment: It would help for your question to say what effect you're trying to achieve with the word or phrase you're seeking. That is, what's the connotation, nuance, etc beyond "good English" that the phrase "*one thing in common*" doesn't have?

Comment: Try "one commonality." To me, it sounds more professional and academic. Plus, it is more economical.

Comment: @rhetorician, can you elaborate, interesting indeed. Thanks.

Comment: You may not be sure that you're conveying your message in a way that matters. But the question doesn't say what the message is, or what matters, so it's difficult for anyone else to suggest something which does what you want. You haven't said what you want. (As you say, "one thing in common" is perfectly grammatical: what's wrong with that?)

Comment: @AndrewLeach, "user experience" is what basically all websites have. It's used in such context .

Comment: I'd accept the phrase *one thing in common* as "good English" with "proper grammar" in a "professional" or "academic" work, unless the context dictates otherwise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as *unclear* because I'm not sure what you're looking for that the phrase *one thing in common* doesn't express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got down to write this sentence, and it seems more complete to the context as a whole. Thanks a lot, to **[@rhetorician](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/32623/rhetorician)** who provided me with the word: **commonalit**y .

My written sentence:

> nonetheless, perhaps the commonality they all share is the elements of
> user experience.

This is very good indeed.

Comment: Yes, very good. You could shorten the sentence even further by saying, "Nonetheless, perhaps their commonality is the element of user experience." (Commonality MEANS something they all share.) Don

Comment: I find this whole discussion confusing.  Are all these web sites providing the same user experience, or are we merely saying that all web sites interface with users?  Or is the "they" who have only one thing in common the  people who share the trials and tribulations of user interfaces?  Whatever is this about?

Comment: More frequently found would be "the common feature."  But saying that two things have something in common is perfectly acceptable in formal writing.

Answer (score 0):

"Tangential", as in how a tangent line or plane only touches a curve or sphere at a single point?

Comment: x=could you provide links for the information you are giving?

Comment: No; 'tangential' has a strongly idiomatic default sense when used metaphorically. It focuses on the 'out into space', diverging quickly from the point of correspondence aspect rather than the 'common factor'.